# Is it true that $e^{f(\xi)}\leq C_M(1+|\xi|)^M$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb Z^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ such that: $$|f(\xi)|\leq C(1+|\xi|)^m,$$ for some $m\in\mathbb R$ and constant $C>0$ which may depend on $m$ but not on $\xi$.

Is it true that there are $M\in\mathbb N$ and $C_M>0$ such that $$e^{f(\xi)}\leq C_M (1+|\xi|)^M?$$

Thanks.

**Sketch.** Well, I still don't get to a conclusion but I sketched a proof for the case $m\leq 0$:

On contrary, for every $j\in\mathbb N$ there would exist $\xi_j\in\mathbb Z^n$ such that $$e^{f(\xi_j)}> (1+|\xi_j|)^j.$$ Hence $$C_m (1+|\xi_j|)^m\geq f(\xi_j)=\ln(e^{f(\xi_j)})> j\ln(1+|\xi_j|).$$ Suppose $m\leq 0$ and $\xi_j\neq 0$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$. Then $(1+|\xi_j|)^m\leq 1$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$ and $1+|\xi_j|\geq 2$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$. Hence we would get $$C_m>j\ln(1+|\xi_j|)\geq j\ln(2)\Leftrightarrow j<\frac{C_m}{\ln(2)},$$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$, a contradiction. Anyway, I don't know if I can suppose $\xi_j\neq 0$ for every $j\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so: Take $f(n) = n$. Then $e^{f(n)}$ admits no polynomial bound.

Edit: I think you are making this more complicated than need be! If  $m \le 0$ , then $f$ is bounded, and  $|f(n)| \le A$ for some $A$,  so $e^{f(n)} \le e^{|f(n)|} \le e^A$...